# How can I append files using export-csv for PowerShell 2?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

```
$filesremoved | export-csv -Path E:\Code\powershell\logs\filesremoved.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

I've also tried

```
$filesremoved | export-csv -Path E:\Code\powershell\logs\filesremoved.txt -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
```

The file appears to be overwritten every time. Is there a way to keep adding content to the file?

I get errors

```
Export-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Append'.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21047532/1035521

Comment: for those who are looking for solution please see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242541/alternative-to-append-export-csv-powershell/38243306#38243306

Comment: best solution for this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242541/alternative-to-append-export-csv-powershell?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-Append` parameter of `Export-Csv` doesn't exist until PowerShell 3.0.

One way to work around it in PowerShell 2.0 is to import the existing CSV, create some new rows, append the two collections, and export again. For example, suppose test.csv:

```
"A","B","C"
"A1","B1","C1"
"A2","B2","C2"
```

You could append some rows to this CSV file using a script like this:

```
$rows = [Object[]] (Import-Csv "test.csv")
$addRows = 3..5 | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "A" = "A{0}" -f $_
    "B" = "B{0}" -f $_
    "C" = "C{0}" -f $_
  }
}
$rows + $addRows | Export-Csv "test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Run this script and the content of test2.csv will be:

```
"A","B","C"
"A1","B1","C1"
"A2","B2","C2"
"A3","B3","C3"
"A4","B4","C4"
"A5","B5","C5"
```

Comment: It outputs numbers in the range 3 to 5. (Enter `3..5` at a PowerShell prompt to see it.) I used it in the code above merely as a way to generate more data for the CSV.

Comment: I get an error `doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.`

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce. I just opened a PowerShell window, entered `3..5`, and it output three numbers (3, 4, and 5).

Comment: sorry, I meant at this line of your code `$rows + $addRows`

Comment: Just tested again and it works for me in PowerShell 2.0 and later.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart In the case that the file contains zero or one records, the result of `Import-Csv` is not an arry of size zero or one, but a single object. You need to declare `$rows` to `[PsObject[]] $rows` to fix the `op_Addition` error.

Comment: I get the same error. I did declare row as a PSObject. $rows = @() then $rows = new-object PSObject then $rows = import-csv file.txt

Comment: Updated code to cast as array to avoid the problem of 0 or 1 objects.

Answer (score 8):

I have no idea what `$filesremoved` include, but to append CSV-output in PS2.0, you could try somthing like this:

```
$filesremoved | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append -FilePath "test2.csv"
```

`Select-Object -Skip 1` is used to remove the header. You should however specify the columns-order you need, the delimiter and maybe encoding, like:

```
$filesremoved | Select-Object -Property Name, Date | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";"  -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append -Encoding ascii -FilePath "test2.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
$CSVContent = $filesremoved | ConvertTo-Csv
$CSVContent[2..$CSVContent.count] | add-content E:\Code\powershell\logs\filesremoved.txt
```