# How to search a string in multiple files and return file name with line number/text in an Excel or csv in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, search, line

I have found an answer that gives the list of files in powershell here

[How to search a string in multiple files and return the names of files in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153750/how-to-search-a-string-in-multiple-files-and-return-the-names-of-files-in-powers)

but I need to know the line number and line text also where that text is found. After this I need to write the output to an excel or csv.

edit:
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "ftp" | Write-Host script is giving me the output as C:\codes\prog1.txt:10:FTP but I want the output as path - C:\codes\prog1.txt line number-10 Line text-FTP "server1" in Excel

Comment: Please provide a minimal working sample code describing your problems and efforts!

Comment: Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "ftp" | Write-Host  script is giving me the output as C:\codes\prog1.txt:10:FTP but I want the output as path - C:\codes\prog1.txt line number-10 Line text-FTP "server1" in Excel

Comment: Please edit the question and post the code there instead of in a comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (don't know if you only want the filename or the path to the file, just remove the one you dont want):

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "string" | Select-Object path,line,linenumber,filename | Export-Csv -Path c:\somepath\result.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Oggew, yes it worked as expected. Thanks a lot for quick response.!!

Comment: Hi I am using the below script for as many strings I want but there is problem with the below script that is creating separate excel for each string in the input file. I tried creating just one file but it is overriding the previous content so came up with different files for different string. Do you know any way on how to append data in the same(one) excel sheet??
$content = Get-Content ..\KeyWord.txt 
cd "..\Test\"
ForEach ($Word in $content){
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern $Word | Select-Object path,line,linenumber,filename | Export-csv -Path "..\result_$word.csv"
 }

Comment: What if you add -Append like this: "Export-Csv -Path c:\somepath\file.csv -Append"

"Adds the CSV output to the end of the specified file. Without this parameter, Export-CSV replaces the file contents without warning."

Comment: The only problem is the system where I need to run the script, its having Powershell 2.0 so if you know any alternative of append?

Comment: This should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048650/how-can-i-append-files-using-export-csv-for-powershell-2

Comment: ($content = Get-Content ..\KeyWord.txt cd "..\Test\" ForEach ($Word in $content){ Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern $Word | Select-Object path,line,linenumber,filename | Export-csv -Path "..\result_$word.csv") This is the current code which generates suppose 4-5 csv files depending upon the keywords I am giving. There is a way to do it thru append but with the link you just shared http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048650/how-can-i-append-files-using-export-csv-for-powershell-2 does not do what I need.