# Alternative to Append export-csv powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I add user logon and logout tracking script

I found that some computers do not export csv as they have powershell 2.0 because append is not supported is there any alternative?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
####**** Tracking user logon *****#####

$username = $env:USERNAME
$computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$ipv4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1 | foreach { $_.ipv4address } 
$ipv6 = Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1 | foreach { $_.ipv6address }  
$timeformat='MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt'
$time = (Get-Date).ToString($timeformat)
$action = 'Logon'
$filedate = 'MM-dd-yyyy'
$filename = 'CompInfo' + ' ' + $(Get-Date).ToString($filedate)

#Creates custom table and sorts the information
$table=  New-Object –TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            'Date/Time' = $time
            'Username' = $username
            'ComputerName'= $computername
            'IPv4 Address' = $ipv4
            'IPv6 Address' = $ipv6
       'Notes/Action' = $action
} | Select date/time, username, computername, 'IPv4 Address', 'IPv6 Address', notes/action 
$table | Export-Csv "d:\$env:username.csv" -NoClobber -append  -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Multiple options. One would be to `Import-Csv` the existing file, add new rows and `Export-Csv` again. Another would be to settle on another format (or comma-separate the values manually)

Comment: I dont think its valid answer

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment ;-) There's no `-Append` equivalent for `Export-Csv` in PowerShell 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#Thanks to Dmitry Sotnikov
#https://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/export-csv-append/
#### Append CSV Powershell 2.0
function Export-CSV {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Delimiter',
  SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='Medium')]
param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true,
           ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
 [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]
 ${InputObject},

 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
 [Alias('PSPath')]
 [System.String]
 ${Path},

 #region -Append (added by Dmitry Sotnikov)
 [Switch]
 ${Append},
 #endregion 

 [Switch]
 ${Force},

 [Switch]
 ${NoClobber},

 [ValidateSet('Unicode','UTF7','UTF8','ASCII','UTF32',
                  'BigEndianUnicode','Default','OEM')]
 [System.String]
 ${Encoding},

 [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Delimiter', Position=1)]
 [ValidateNotNull()]
 [System.Char]
 ${Delimiter},

 [Parameter(ParameterSetName='UseCulture')]
 [Switch]
 ${UseCulture},

 [Alias('NTI')]
 [Switch]
 ${NoTypeInformation})

begin
{
 # This variable will tell us whether we actually need to append
 # to existing file
 $AppendMode = $false

 try {
  $outBuffer = $null
  if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
  {
      $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
  }
  $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Export-Csv',
    [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)


 #String variable to become the target command line
 $scriptCmdPipeline = ''

 # Add new parameter handling
 #region Dmitry: Process and remove the Append parameter if it is present
 if ($Append) {

  $PSBoundParameters.Remove('Append') | Out-Null

  if ($Path) {
   if (Test-Path $Path) {        
    # Need to construct new command line
    $AppendMode = $true

    if ($Encoding.Length -eq 0) {
     # ASCII is default encoding for Export-CSV
     $Encoding = 'ASCII'
    }

    # For Append we use ConvertTo-CSV instead of Export
    $scriptCmdPipeline += 'ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation '

    # Inherit other CSV convertion parameters
    if ( $UseCulture ) {
     $scriptCmdPipeline += ' -UseCulture '
    }
    if ( $Delimiter ) {
     $scriptCmdPipeline += " -Delimiter '$Delimiter' "
    } 

    # Skip the first line (the one with the property names) 
    $scriptCmdPipeline += ' | Foreach-Object {$start=$true}'
    $scriptCmdPipeline += '{if ($start) {$start=$false} else {$_}} '

    # Add file output
    $scriptCmdPipeline += " | Out-File -FilePath '$Path'"
    $scriptCmdPipeline += " -Encoding '$Encoding' -Append "

    if ($Force) {
     $scriptCmdPipeline += ' -Force'
    }

    if ($NoClobber) {
     $scriptCmdPipeline += ' -NoClobber'
    }   
   }
  }
 } 



 $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }

 if ( $AppendMode ) {
  # redefine command line
  $scriptCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock(
      $scriptCmdPipeline
    )
 } else {
  # execute Export-CSV as we got it because
  # either -Append is missing or file does not exist
  $scriptCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock(
      [string]$scriptCmd
    )
 }

 # standard pipeline initialization
 $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline(
        $myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
 $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)

 } catch {
   throw
 }

}

process
{
  try {
      $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
  } catch {
      throw
  }
}

end
{
  try {
      $steppablePipeline.End()
  } catch {
      throw
  }
}

}

#### Append CSV Powershell 2.0
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
####**** Tracking user logon *****#####

$username = $env:USERNAME
$computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$ipv4 = Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1 | foreach { $_.ipv4address } 
$ipv6 = Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1 | foreach { $_.ipv6address }  
$timeformat='MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt'
$time = (Get-Date).ToString($timeformat)
$action = 'Logon'
$filedate = 'MM-dd-yyyy'
$filename = 'CompInfo' + ' ' + $(Get-Date).ToString($filedate)

#Creates custom table and sorts the information
$table=  New-Object –TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            'Date/Time' = $time
            'Username' = $username
            'ComputerName'= $computername
            'IPv4 Address' = $ipv4
            'IPv6 Address' = $ipv6
       'Notes/Action' = $action
} | Select date/time, username, computername, 'IPv4 Address', 'IPv6 Address', notes/action 
$table | Export-Csv "D:\$env:username.csv" -NoClobber -Append  -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This saved me from re-writing my script! :) Thanks!