# How can I compare the content of 3 directories in powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, comparison, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

After looking into this for a while, I've found a lot of people trying to do the same thing but I haven't yet been able to find a complete answer so I'm hoping someone can help us!

What I would like to do is give 2 directories, A and B, and compare everything inside A to everything inside B and if there are any files or folders in B that are not in A then generate an output file detailing the path to the item that is in B and not A. From Here, Id like to use the list of items and say if any of the items in these paths contain something different to the files in 2 directories (the names will be the same so documents\folder\B.txt contains something different to desktop\folder\B.txt) generate another list showing what is different or showing the file path to items that are different if I cant show the text that is different.

I've looked into doing this with `.hash` but I'm not sure if that's to best way to go about it? something like:

```
$SourceDocs = Get-ChildItem –Path C:\Documents1 | foreach  {Get-FileHash –Path $_.FullName} $DestDocs = Get-ChildItem –Path C:\Documents2 | foreach  {Get-FileHash –Path $_.FullName}
```

In terms of what I have for the physical comparison, I originally was trying to do a 3-way comparison so the code below isn't accurate but its all I've got as yet.

```
$folderA = 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Folder A'
$folderB = 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Folder B'
$folderC = 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Folder C'
$AChild = Get-ChildItem $folderA -Recurse
$BChild = Get-ChildItem $folderB -Recurse
$CChild = Get-ChildItem $folderC -Recurse
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $AChild -DifferenceObject $BChild, $CChildcode
```

After looking into this further, Ive found out it might be better to use 3.0 rather than 2.0 so I can use -Dir more efficiently.

Any questions, let me know.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is answer to what you want:
**What I would like to do is give 2 directories, A and B, and compare everything inside A to everything inside B and if there are any files or folders in B that are not in A then generate an output file detailing the path to the item that is in B and not A.**

```
 $folder1 = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Folder A"
        $folder2 = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Folder B"


        # Get all files under $folder1, filter out directories
        $firstFolder = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder1 | Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer }

        $failedCount = 0
        $i = 0
        $totalCount = $firstFolder.Count
        $firstFolder | ForEach-Object {
            $i = $i + 1
            Write-Progress -Activity "Searching Files" -status "Searching File  $i of     $totalCount" -percentComplete ($i / $firstFolder.Count * 100)
            # Check if the file, from $folder1, exists with the same path under $folder2
            If ( Test-Path ( $_.FullName.Replace($folder1, $folder2) ) ) {
                # Compare the contents of the two files...
                If ( Compare-Object (Get-Content $_.FullName) (Get-Content $_.FullName.Replace($folder1, $folder2) ) ) {
                    # List the paths of the files containing diffs
                    $fileSuffix = $_.FullName.TrimStart($folder1)
                    $failedCount = $failedCount + 1
                    Write-Host "$fileSuffix is on each server, but does not match"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $fileSuffix = $_.FullName.TrimStart($folder1)
                $failedCount = $failedCount + 1
                Write-Host "$fileSuffix is only in folder 1"
$fileSuffix | Out-File "$env:userprofile\desktop\folder1.txt" -Append
            }
        }

        $secondFolder = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder2 | Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer }

        $i = 0
        $totalCount = $secondFolder.Count
        $secondFolder | ForEach-Object {
            $i = $i + 1
            Write-Progress -Activity "Searching for files only on second folder" -status "Searching File  $i of $totalCount" -percentComplete ($i / $secondFolder.Count * 100)
            # Check if the file, from $folder2, exists with the same path under $folder1
            If (!(Test-Path($_.FullName.Replace($folder2, $folder1))))
            {
                $fileSuffix = $_.FullName.TrimStart($folder2)
                $failedCount = $failedCount + 1
                Write-Host "$fileSuffix is only in folder 2"
$fileSuffix | Out-File "$env:userprofile\desktop\folder2.txt" -Append
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! this looks great however, is there anyway I can output the "(File Path) is only in folder 1/2" to a file rather than just showing in powershell?

Comment: $fileSuffix | Out-File D:\lo.txt -Append  add this line after write-host append do not support on powershell 2 see my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242541/alternative-to-append-export-csv-powershell

Comment: modified answer append do not support on powershell 2 see my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242541/alternative-to-append-export-csv-powershell

Comment: That's amazing! Could you advise on the second bit as well?

Comment: I didn't understand what it means " generate another list showing what is different or showing the file path to items that are different if I cant show the text that is different."

Comment: So I am going to have 2 lots of files, I would like to generate a file to say Document 1 or File A contains "AAAA" on line 1, if this is only in the file A's document 1 and not file B's document 1. however, if I cannot drill down this far then just a file to say desktop\file1\1 contains something different to desktop desktop\file2\1. Hope that make sense!

Comment: the text file name folder1 will only contain files that only exist in folder1 and not in folder 2 it wll show you the path of the folder.

 same with folder 2 it ill only contain files that only exist in folder2 and not in folder 1 it wll show you the path of the folder

Comment: Apologies, I dont think Ive made my intentions clear! so what I am looking to do is use this for client upgrades at work so I will have the old install files, the new install files and the clients current install files. My intention is to  compare the old files and the new ones as youve helped with above and then use the lists created to compare the content of these new and old files against what the client has currently so if they have any customisation, I know I need to customise the new files before upgrade. Ideally if I can I would like to show exactly what the differences are or the path