# In powershell, how can I append one table to another and export to CSV?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm relatively new to Powershell, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I need to make multiple SQL queries and store the results to all of the queries in the same csv. With Powershell 3.0 I could use Export-CSV -Append, but unfortunately I need to use Powershell 2.0. Here is what I have right now.

```
#Connection Strings
$Database = "DB"
$Server = "localhost"

#Export File
$AttachmentPath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SQLData.csv"

# Connect to SQL and query data, extract data to SQL Adapter
$SqlQuery = "select * from DB.dbo.DB1"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security = True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$nRecs = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$nRecs | Out-Null

#Populate Hash Table
$objTable = $DataSet.Tables[0]

#Export Hash Table to CSV File
$objTable | Export-CSV $AttachmentPath

Write-Output "REPORT: Successfully created ${AttachmentPath}"
```

This will successfully create and export my table into a csv file that looks like this:

```
Table 1
----------------
col1(int)  col2(string)  col3(string)
col1(int)  col2(string)  col3(string)
```

but now I want to run a different query the exact same way

```
# Connect to SQL and query data, extract data to SQL Adapter
$SqlQuery = "select * from DB.dbo.DB2"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security = True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$nRecs = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$nRecs | Out-Null

#Populate Hash Table
$objTable = $DataSet.Tables[0]

#IN POWERSHELL 3.0 THIS WOULD WORK
$objTable | Export-CSV $AttachmentPath -Append
```

and append it onto the first table. The final CSV would look like this:

```
Table 1
----------------
col1(int)  col2(string)  col3(string)
col1(int)  col2(string)  col3(string)

Table 2
----------------
col1(string)  col2(int)  col3(int)
col1(string)  col2(int)  col3(int)
```

I can't find any way to do this, any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

Found a workaround by exporting the second query to a csv,

```
$objTable | Export-CSV $AttachmentPath
```

Then I used the Get-Content and Add-Content cmdlets to append to the first csv. It's hacky but it works. If you have anything better let me know!

```
$file2=Get-Content $AttachmentPath

Add-Content "SQLData.csv" "`n"
Add-Content "SQLData.csv" $file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use `UNION` in your query like below to get a merged data from both table

```
$SqlQuery = "select * from DB.dbo.DB1 UNION select * from DB.dbo.DB2"
```

Then you can use `Export-CSV filename.csv` commandlet to export the data to a CSV file (OR) see this thread [How to export data to CSV in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047185/how-to-export-data-to-csv-in-powershell)

Comment: I simplified the queries for the question, but I don't think I can use union because the columns returned for the first query have different datatypes than the columns returned in the second query, and I'm grouping and ordering by different things. Also it's worth noting that I'll be doing this with more than two tables. I have one script in which I need to combine 15 tables into a single CSV.

Comment: While Union might not be acceptable for all situations, it is possible to merge two queries... just cast the output of numbers and dates to varchar/char. > Blockquote Table 1
----------------
SELECT Cast(col1(int) as varchar(7)) col1,  col2(string)  col3(string)
FROM [Table 1]
UNION ALL----------------
col1(string)  col2(int)  col3(int)
col1(string)  col2(int)  col3(int)

Answer (score 0):

While Union might not be acceptable for all situations, it is possible to merge two queries... just cast the output of numbers and dates to varchar/char.

> SELECT Cast(col1(int) as varchar(7)) as col1,  col2(string) as col2,
>   col3(string) 
>   FROM [Table 1] 
>   UNION ALL SELECT  col1(string), Cast(col2(int) as varchar(7)), 
>   Cast(col3(int) as varchar(7))

Just make sure you aren't truncating any data and you can mash em together.

Of course with 15 tables joining them in powershell would seem easier to maintain.