# how can I export Active Directory thumbnailPhoto for bulk of users and name it with their email address?

Tags: scripting, active-directory, attributes, export

I'm using the following script to export thumbnailPhoto from AD and name the exported photos by username (SamAccountName).

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties thumbnailPhoto | ? {$_.thumbnailPhoto}

foreach ($user in $users) { $name = $user.SamAccountName + ".jpg" $user.thumbnailPhoto | Set-Content $name -Encoding byte }
```

How can I export the photos and name it with e-mail address for example **name@domain.com.jpg**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a csv by piping the content of the array through [Export-CSV](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176825.aspx).

```
$results = @()
foreach ( 
...
}
$results | export-csv -Path c:\temp\so.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

See [How to export data to CSV in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047185/how-to-export-data-to-csv-in-powershell)

Comment: Hi. the output must be a JPG photo and its name user@domain.com

Answer (score 0):

FYI ...
This is the answer.

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties mail,thumbnailPhoto  

foreach ($user in $users) {
$name = $user.mail + ".jpg"  
$user.thumbnailPhoto | Set-Content $name -Encoding byte
}
```