# Identify given computer domain if they have Skype for Business Application

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I need your help and suggestion regarding on my PowerShell script, already have the initial program that works for showing it on the terminal screen, my problem is I want to export the output from the terminal screen to CSV file

Inside the `computername.txt`:

```
d-pol-abanaga
d-pol-pcspc
d-pol-eplete
```

Output Terminal Screen:

```
PS C:\Users\ksaycon\Desktop> ./script.ps1
d-pol-abanaga  No Skype for Business are present
d-pol-pcspc  No Skype for Business are present
d-pol-eplete  No Skype for Business are present
```

This should be on the exported CSV also based from the terminal output:

```
d-pol-abanaga  No Skype for Business are present
d-pol-pcspc  No Skype for Business are present
d-pol-eplete  No Skype for Business are present
```

The code:

```
# Read input file of computer names
$computers = Get-Content C:\pstool\computername.txt
# Loop through each computer name in the array
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    # Test for lync.exe file
    $path = Test-Path "<\\$computer\c$\program files\microsoft office\office15\*>" -Include lync.exe
    # Report if templates are found or not
    if ($path -eq $true) {
        Write-Output $Computer 'Skype for Business are present' |
            Export-Csv -Path "output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    } else {
        if ($path -eq $false) {
            $path16 = Test-Path "<\\$computer\c$\program files\microsoft office\office16\*>" -Include lync.exe
        }
    }

    if ($path16 -eq $true) {
        Write-Output $Computer 'Skype for Business are present' |
            Export-Csv -Path "output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    } else {
        Write-Output $Computer ' No Skype for Business are present' |
            Export-Csv -Path "output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the angular brackets from your paths. Also, does the user running the script have admin privileges on the remote computers? Otherwise they don't have access to administrative shares (`\\$computer\C$`).

Comment: Thanks but my issue here is when exporting to CSV it has empty data, didnt copy the exact output in the csv file. :(

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and show a [mcve]. We cannot help you when your question doesn't allow us to understand or reproduce the problem you're facing.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Already edit, my apology if my questions has too many flowery stuffs. I had to express it many times. Please do understand me. Thank you

Comment: Depends on what you want to export. You could use `Export-Csv -Append` inside the loop, but you cannot export `Write-Host` output to a file as that output goes directly to the host console. If you want output processed via pipeline or redirection use `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host`.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers, tried adding this inside the Write-Output, got errors:
IF ($path16 -eq $true ) {  Write-Output $Computer 'Skype for Business are present' |Export-Csv -Path "output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append}

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers please refer also to the code, already updated.

Comment: Use `Add-Content` with `Write-Output`. `Export-Csv` is for exporting objects to CSV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be a lot easier to loop over the Office versions you are interested in and break the loop as soon as Skype is found in one of them. Next create an object with the information you need and colect that in a variable `$result`.

Something like this:

```
# Loop through each computer name in the array from file 'C:\pstool\computername.txt'
# collect the data for export in variable $result
$result = foreach ($computer in (Get-Content 'C:\pstool\computername.txt')) {
    # Test for lync.exe file in Office versions 15 and 16
    $skype = 'Not present'
    for ($v = 15; $v -lt 17; $v++) {
        if (Test-Path -Path "\\$computer\c$\program files\microsoft office\office$v\*" -Include lync.exe) {
            $skype = 'Present'
            break
        }
    }

    # emit a PSObject to collect in the $result variable
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Computer'           = $computer
        'Skype for Business' = $skype
    }
}

# output to console
$result

# write results to CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path "D:\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot see in your question how you tried to export the CSV, this would be the most interisting part.

Copied the export part from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21047532/12029319

```
# Read input file of computer names
$computers = Get-Content C:\pstool\computername.txt
$Application = "lync.exe"
$results = @()
# Loop through each computer name in the array
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    # Test for $Application file
    $path = Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\program files\microsoft office\office15\*" -Include $Application
    # Report if templates are found or not
    if ($path -eq $true ) {
        Write-Host $Computer 'Skype for Business are present'
    }
    else {
        if ($path -eq $false) {
            $path16 = Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\program files\microsoft office\office16\*" -Include $Application
        }
    }

    if ($path16 -eq $true) {
        $result = 'Skype for Business are present'
        Write-Host $Computer $result
        $details = @{      
            ComputerName = $Computer
            Result       = $result    
        }
    }
    else {
        $result = 'No Skype for Business are present'
        Write-Host $Computer $result
        $details = @{      
            ComputerName = $Computer
            Result       = $result
        }
    }
    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details  
}
$results | export-csv -Path c:\pstool\Check_for_lync.csv -NoTypeInformation
```